# Solve a differential system of equations in time

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

I am trying to solve a system of 3 equations and 3 unknown variables that change in time (Tw(t), Tcor(t), Texit(t)).

```
Clear[Tw];
Clear[Tcor];
Clear[Texit];
hb = 159.96;
hl = 45.90;
tf = 1400;
hfg = 2257.1*1000;
cpw = 4.2*1000;
ab = 0.0022765;
al = 0.030615;
Tf = 1450;
qm = 0.4474;
T0 = 298;
cpm = 4.01005*1000;

eq1 = Derivative[1][Tw][
    t] == (hb*ab*(((Tf - Tcor[t])/2) - Tw[t]) + 
      hl*al*(((Tcor[t] - Texit[t])/2) - Tw[t]) + 0.08*hfg - 
      cpw*Tw[t]*0.08)/(cpw*0.08*t);
eq2 = Derivative[1][Tcor][t] == 
   2*(-hb*ab*(((Tf - Tcor[t])/2) - Tw[t]) + qm*cpm*(Tf - T0) - 
       qm*cpm*(Tcor[t] - T0))/(cpm*qm);
eq3 = Derivative[1][Texit][t] == 
   2*(-hl*al*(((Tcor[t] - Texit[t])/2) - Tw[t]) + 
       qm*cpm*(Tcor[t] - T0) - qm*cpm*(Texit[t] - T0))/(cpm*qm);

sol = NDSolve[{eq1, eq2, eq3, Tw[0.000001] == 300, 
    Tcor[0.000001] == 750, Texit[0.000001] == 300}, 
   Tw, {t, 0.000001, 6000}, Tcor, {t, 0.000001, 6000}, 
   Texit, {t, 0.000001, 6000}];
Plot[Evaluate[Tw[t] /. sol], {t, 0.000001, 6000}]
```

It is not working because 2 messages appear...
a) Duplicate variable t found in the expression
b) The expression is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing.

Although there are already a few answers about similar questions, I have no idea to solve this whatsoever.

Plus, it should also be imposed the condition of maximum Tw < 375 kelvin. As it simulates water boiling.

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the two last commands by

```
sol = NDSolve[{eq1, eq2, eq3, Tw[0.000001] == 300, Tcor[0.000001] == 750, Texit[0.000001] == 300}, {Tw, Tcor, Texit}, {t, 0.000001, 6000}]
Plot[Evaluate[Tw[t] /. sol], {t, 0.000001, 6000}]
```

Comment: I was not expecting that it was a syntax problem, thanks a lot!

Comment: By any chance, do you have any idea how to impose a horizontal asymptode at Tw = 375?